# A group of order $108$ has a proper normal subgroup of order $\geq 6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem**: Let $G$ be a group of order $108 = 2^23^3$. Prove that $G$ has a proper **normal** subgroup of order $n \geq 6$.

**My attempt**: From the Sylow theorems, if $n_3$ and $n_2$ denote the number of subgroups of order $27$ and $4$, respectively, in $G$, then $n_3 = 1$ or $4$, since $n_3 \equiv 1$ (mod $3$) and $n_3~|~2^2$, and $n_2 = 1, 3, 9$ or $27$, because $n_2~|~3^3$.

Now, I don't know what else to do. I tried assuming $n_3 = 4$ and seeing if this leads to a contradiction, but I'm not even sure that this can't happen. I'm allowed to use only the basic results of group theory (the Sylow theorems being the most sophisticated tools).

Any ideas are welcome; thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use group actions?

Comment: @Brian if you mean things like the Class Equation, then yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\,P\,$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup. of $\,G\,$ and let the group act on the left cosets of $\,P\,$ by left (or right) shift. This action determines a homomorphism of $\,G\,$ on $\,S_4\,$ whose kernel *has* to be non-trivial (why? Compare orders!) and either of order $27$ or of order $9$ (a subgroup of $ \, P \, $, say) , so in any case the claim's proved.

Comment: Yes thanks, it was a typo and has already been corrected: it is a Sylow 3 subgroup. Whether the kernel of the induced homom. $\,\phi:G\to S_4\,$ by the action is a subgroup of $\,P\,$ of order 9 or $\,P\,$ itself we're cool since this is a proper subgroup of order greater than 6...

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, I understand it now. Still, the action is on the left cosets of $P$, rather than $P$ itself, right? It also follows that this homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow S_4$ cannot be surjective, since we would then have $G/\ker(\phi) \simeq S_4$, which can't happen (again because of the orders).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited and thanks.

Comment: @ DonAntoino I have to understood your point but how to conclude $G$ have normal subgroup of order 9 and 27.

Comment: 9 **or** 27, @user120386 . $\;|G|=108\;,\;\;|S_4|=24\;$ , and by the regular action of $\;G\;$ on the left cosets of $\;P\;$ we get a subgroup of $\;P\;$ which is *normal* in $\;G\;$ and at least of order $\;\frac{|G|}{|S_4|}=4.5\;$ **and** a divisor of $\;27\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I have the same confusion as user120386 's... We can only deduce from the fact that the order of normal subgroup is $ \ge 5 $ and it is also a divisor of $ 108=2^2\times 3^3 $ to conclude that it is $\ge 6$ which is what the question asks us to prove. I didn't see any reason why we can deduce that the order is a divisor of $27$.

Comment: @user549397 Because the kernel of that homomorphism $\;G\to S_4\;$ is a subgroup of $\;P\;$ , of course. You may want to read about the regular action, the core of a group and etc.

Comment: @user549397 Sure. Check that the kernel of the homomorphism $\;G\to S_4\;$ associated with the action of $\;G\;$ on the left cosets of $\;P\;$ is precisely *the core* of $\;P\;$ , namely: $\;\bigcap_{g\in G} g^{-1}Pg\;$ . This group is characterized by being the maximal normal subgroup in $\;G\;$ **which is contained in** $\;P\;$ ... If you make it this far then you already got what you wanted. This is standard stuff, for example in Rotman's book.

Comment: @DonAntonio Aha! Finally, I get it... Thank you!

Comment: @DonAntonio Kernel of the homomorphism can only be of order $9$. Clearly $\mid kernel \mid \neq 1,3$ and also $kernel \neq P$, since P is not normal in $G$. Thus only option left is that $\mid ker \mid=9$.