# Group of order $108$ not simple using Sylow theorems on Sylow-$2$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Show that any group of order $108$ is not simple.

I can show this using Sylow theorems on Sylow-$3$ subgroups. I was not able to completely justify for Sylow-$2$ subgroups though.

In case of Sylow-$2$ subgroups we have the following :

$n_2|27$ and $n_2\equiv1 \mod2\implies n_2=1,3,9,27$, where $n_2$ is the number of distinct Sylow-$2$ subgroups. For the case $n_2=1$ or $n_2=27$, its quite straightforward and the case $n_2=3$ can be shown using extended Cayley theorem.

For $n_2=9$, using extended Cayley theorem $\exists\; \theta:G\to S_9$ a group homomorphism. But I am not able to show that $\ker\theta\neq\{1\}$. Also if I assume $ H$ and $K$ are two Sylow-$2$ subgroups of order $4$, then $H\cap K\trianglelefteq G$ but I cannot show $|H\cap K|\neq1$ necessarily.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed for this case $n_2=9$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: My question is more specific than mentioned in the link.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I am searching for another helpful link using $n_2$ instead of $n_3$. But I think, the argument with $n_3$ is shorter, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178214/a-group-of-order-108-has-a-proper-normal-subgroup-of-order-geq-6).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I agree completely. But just to have fun and more understanding I was trying with Sylow-$2$ subgroups $n_2$  but unable to argue for the case $n_2=9$.

Comment: I doubt if in your difficult case that you can show there are two Sylow-2-subgroups which intersect non-trivially, so you'll have to look at the 3-structure at some stage. I have in mind the subgroup $\langle (123), (456), (789), (23)(56), (23)(89) \rangle$ of $A_9$.